# OpenGL correct matrix transformation order to rotate object at fixed point

Tags: python, opengl, matrix, rotation, matrix-multiplication

I am using OpenGL with Python, and have the following code:

```
glTranslatef(0, 0, -3.0)
glRotatef(rotation * 100.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
square.render()
```

- where rotation is a integer which increases by frame and `square.render()` simply renders a quad to the screen.

Most sources will advise translating the matrix and then rotating it, as I have done here. However, when the quad renders to the screen, it rotates around a circle rather than a fixed point. My issue is that I want the quad to rotate around a fixed point, and I have been unsuccessful thus far in doing so. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would consider a different way of describing this in the future. When I read ***"fixed point"*** in the context of computer graphics, the first thing that comes to mind is an integer data type that has a scale to define a radix point... maybe "fixed location?" :)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ah, yes. Damn these technicalities always escaping me! Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about `glRotatef()` as if you actually *"draw"* an axis, which starts from (0, 0, 0) and points to whatever coordinates you give to it. Your example uses the (0, 1, 0) which is the World Y axis.

But let's say, you want to rotate your `P` point (10, 10, 0) around the `A` axis [(3, 3, 3), (3, 4, 3)].This axis -- as you can see -- is parallel with Y.

First you have to translate your whole world so now your `A` axis will lie on World Y axis.

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )
glTranslatef( 3, 3, 3 )
```

Now you have to rotate everything around the World Y axis:

```
glRotatef( rotation*100.0, 0, 1, 0 )
```

And then you have to translate it back:

```
glTranslatef( -3, -3, -3 )
```

And now you can draw your `P` point:

```
glBegin( GL_POINTS )
glVertex3f( 10, 10, 0 )
glEnd()
```

---

*NOTE: forget my stupid glBegin/End example, it is ancient, use VAOs and VBOs!*

---

I don't know what framework are you using, but here is a pretty basic example in pyglet:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window( 256, 256 )

x = 0
def update(dt):
    global x
    x += 1


@window.event
def on_draw():
    global x

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef( 128, 128, 0 )
    glRotatef( x, 0, 0, 1 )
    glTranslatef( -128, -128, 0 )

    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES )
    glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 )
    glVertex3f( 128, 128, 0 )
    glColor3f( 0, 1, 0 )
    glVertex3f( 200, 128, 0 )
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 1 )
    glVertex3f( 200, 200, 0 )
    glEnd()

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60)
pyglet.app.run()
```

[AND THE RESULT IS HERE!](http://cl.ly/0L3e3Z1w2c2Y)

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much, this makes a lot more sense now and I was able to fix my problem! :)